react native vector icons showing as question mark within a square box
I cannot to get the react-native-vector-Icons to show in Ios.

I have created a new Folder within Ios called fonts

info.plist contains the necessary fonts

**I cannot add the Fonts to copy bundler in xcode because i then get below errors **(note this is a snippet of the errors)
Target 'projectname' in project 'projectname'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-sailraceapp2' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-sailraceapp2.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods' via options '-lBVLinearGradient' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'

Here is example of my code
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       {console.log('Attempting to render the Direction, Air, icon')}
        <View style={styles.compassContainer}>
         <Icon
          name="direction"
          size={50}
          color="blue"
           style={{transform: [{rotate: `${windDirectionRotation}deg`}]}}
        />
     </View>



Any help would be much appreciated, happy to provide further info if required
Thanks
infoplist
fonts in node modules
fonts in Ios Folder

Attach screenshot of your Fonts folder also add Info.plist file.

I have added links to screenshots.

were you able to establish what is wrong?

Please check on this website, to ensure that Your Icon name is correct or not and the Icon pack you are using is contain that Icon or not

Yes both the above are correct

Which are the steps you completed from https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/HEAD/README.md#ios-setup this guid

Ok so I followed all the steps. I added the react-native.config.js but what I noted was the Copy Bundle Resource is still autopopulating and by from what i understand from the guide this should not be happening?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

what else can i do?

Which icon pack You used ?

entypo I am still having this issue is there anyway i could give you access to the code?
